# Reading back ECPrivateKey from JKS KeyStore

Tags: java, bouncycastle, keystore, elliptic-curve

I'm trying to read back an `ECPrivateKey` (including certificate chain) from a JKS KeyStore as shown in the code below.

```
String storeType = "JKS", storePass = "secret", storePath = "c:/keystore.ks";
ECNamedCurveParameterSpec bcParamSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("brainpoolp224r1");
ECNamedCurveSpec jceParamSpec = new ECNamedCurveSpec(bcParamSpec.getName(), bcParamSpec.getCurve(), bcParamSpec.getG(), bcParamSpec.getN(), bcParamSpec.getH(), bcParamSpec.getSeed());

KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
keyPairGenerator.initialize(jceParamSpec);
KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
ECPublicKey publicKey = (ECPublicKey)keyPair.getPublic();
ECPrivateKey privateKey = (ECPrivateKey)keyPair.getPrivate();

Certificate trustCert =  createX509Certificate("CN=CA", "CN=CA", publicKey, privateKey, "SHA224withECDSA");
Certificate[] chain = { createX509Certificate("CN=Client", "CN=CA", publicKey, privateKey, "SHA224withECDSA"), trustCert };

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(storeType);
keyStore.load(null, storePass.toCharArray());
keyStore.setKeyEntry("eckey", privateKey, storePass.toCharArray(), chain);

FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(storePath);
keyStore.store(outputStream, storePass.toCharArray());
outputStream.close();

/* Now read it back */
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(storePath);
KeyStore keyStore2 = KeyStore.getInstance(storeType);
keyStore2.load(inputStream, storePass.toCharArray());

Key privateKey2 = keyStore2.getKey("eckey", storePass.toCharArray());
```

The curve I'm using is not supported by the Sun/Oracle security provider, so I'm using Bouncy Castle. BC is inserted at position 0 in my list of security providers. Storing works fine, reading back fails:

```
java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Unknown named curve: 1.3.36.3.3.2.8.1.1.5
    at sun.security.provider.KeyProtector.recover(KeyProtector.java:338)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:138)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:792)
```

Apparently the JKS KeyStore implementation doesn't loop through the list of security providers. This works fine, however, for other KeyStore types that are supported by BC: `PKCS12` and `BKS`. **Is there a way to use `JKS` as KeyStore type while using BC to recover the key?**

The `createX509Certificate` method used in the code above is given by:

```
private static X509Certificate createX509Certificate(String dn, String issuer, PublicKey publicKey, PrivateKey privateKey, String sigAlg) throws Exception {
    X509V3CertificateGenerator certGenerator = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();
certGenerator.setSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(Math.abs(new Random().nextLong())));
certGenerator.setIssuerDN(new X509Name(issuer));
    certGenerator.setSubjectDN(new X509Name(dn));
    certGenerator.setNotBefore(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
certGenerator.setNotAfter(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
certGenerator.setPublicKey(publicKey);
certGenerator.setSignatureAlgorithm(sigAlg);
X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)certGenerator.generate(privateKey, "BC");
return certificate;
}
```

Comment: I cannot even get past the `keyPairGenerator.initialize(jceParamSpec);` unless I install BC in the first position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My only thought would be to implement your own [Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/Provider.html) that could either proxy "KeyFactory" request to a BouncyCastle provider and the rest to another one that knows about JKS or proxy all requests to BouncyCastle with the exception of the "KeyStore" request. [Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/HowToImplAProvider.html) documentation on how to implement a provider.